# Send button greyed out in enthought canopy when trying to send bug report

Tags: enthought, canopy

I am having couple issues with Enthought so was asked to send a bug report through help, feedback/bug option. But when I am trying to send the report, the send button is greyed out and I couldn't do anything about it. Any advise on how to overcome this as I could not find any help so far. [image: Attached Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the "View Report" option, then copy / paste it into an email to support@enthought.com. Some old versions of Canopy don't accept direct reports except from logged in registered users, so maybe you're on an old version and not logged in at the welcome screen?  The current version is 1.7.4, see https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website. Thanks.